# Calling Apex from Lightning returning a class extending an Abstract class

Tags: lightning, aura

I have found an issue that when calling an Apex method from Lightning that returns a class that extends an abstract class, then only the `@AuraEnabled` getters from the concrete class are returned, the getters from the base abstract class are not.

**BaseThing**

```
public abstract class BaseThing {

    @AuraEnabled
    public String getOne() {
        return '1';
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public String getTwo() {
        return '2';
    }

}
```

**ConcreteThing**

```
public class ConcreteThing extends BaseThing {

    @AuraEnabled
    public String getThree() {
        return '3';
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public String getFour() {
        return '4';
    }

}
```

**NumberController**

```
public class NumberController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static ConcreteThing GetConcreteThing()
    {
        return new ConcreteThing();
    }

}
```

As you can see from the screenshot of the Lightning Inspector, when this Apex action is called only the getters from the concrete class are returned:

[image: View of action from Lightning Inspector]

Is this supposed to be supported, or is this a bug? I can't see anywhere in the Lightning documentation that states that this isn't supported.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me !

Comment: I have added a post to the Salesforce Success sitea https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00002j36DX -- If I don't get a response there I shall open a case with Salesforce.

Comment: Just ran into it myself - in my case I was using a virtual class, with the exact same effect.

Comment: Workaround: serialize in Apex controller and parse in Lightning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have had a response from the product manager at Salesforce that this is indeed a bug. It is logged as `W-3176751`, although it doesn't seem to appear on the known issues site at the moment.

I am awaiting a response regarding it's public visibility on the Known Issues site and the expected fix date.

Comment: After six months, I faced the issue yesterday. Is there maybe an update by now?

Comment: It is still not working. Btw, you can use JSON to serialize/deresialize between controllers if you don't have cycles.

Comment: still seeing this issue as of Late October 2017.  Apparently it's a bug that no one's in a hurry to fix.

Comment: It looks like they may be attempting to fix this in Spring 18 but in the process have introduced a huge issue detailed here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205012/spring-18-breaks-overridden-apex-methods-in-lightning-components