# Calling method of subclass of super class (Apx) from a javascript line in lightning component

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning

```
public virtual class TopLevel {

    @AuraEnabled
    public virtual void getwriter() {
        System.debug('At top level');
    }

    public class lowerLevel extends TopLevel {

        @AuraEnabled
        public override void getwriter() {
            System.debug('Within lowerLevel.writer.');
        }
}
```

I'm trying to call lowerLevel from within my javascript code as such

```
var action = component.get('c.lowerLevel.writer');
action.setCallback(this, function(ret) {});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

But I'm getting the error of

> Uncaught Unknown controller action 'lowerLevel.writer'

It makes sense to me that it should work since the TopLevel is implied (as we can call

```
var action = component.get('c.writer');
```

and in the system debug we'll find "At top level"

My lightning component is defined as such

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="TopLevel">
```

Anyone know how I can make it do what I want?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't actually "allowed", despite the compiler allowing the annotation.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction to doing what I want then?

Comment: Isn't this a case of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/123744/calling-apex-from-lightning-returning-a-class-extending-an-abstract-class ?

Comment: Seems like it. Also, silly question but if I create a subclass should it go into the same file as the main class or in a new file? Or will it not make a difference?